# PHPExcel - Insert shape or checkbox

Tags: php, phpexcel, xlsx

How to insert Shapes or something like checkboxes in a cell with PHPExcel?

I want to create something like this :

[image]

The problem is also I have to check or fill the checkbox dynamically.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: See if this helps [Checkboxes, Radiobuttons](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/53353])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Form elements such as checkboxes aren't supported by PHPExcel, so it isn't possible to do this

Comment: I have xlsx file and I load it with PHPExcel so Is it possible to only check the checkbox with this address `Check Box 3902` ?

Comment: The checkbox is a form element. PHPExcel doesn't read form elements, so the checkbox simply doesn't exist in the worksheets loaded into PHPExcel

Comment: what about the Images? Is it possible to insert a tick image to cell except checkbox form element?

Comment: You can certainly overlay an image on a cell, or simply use a UTF-8 tick or cross character in the cell content

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a way to do it, using font that include checkbox characters.

```php
$objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText(); 

// checked checkbox
$checkbox = $objRichText->createTextRun('R');
$checkbox->getFont()->setName('Wingdings 2');

// empty checkbox
$checkbox = $objRichText->createTextRun('0');
$checkbox->getFont()->setName('Wingdings 2');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($cellPosition, $checkbox);
```

Comment: Use '0' fom wingdings2 instead of 'c' from wingdings for a better sized empty checkbox. Good find to use fonts Max.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to render static checkboxes using unicode characters (not clickable). These characters will work across most operating systems, unlike wingdings, which is a windows font.

```
$objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();

$checkbox = $objRichText->createTextRun('☑'); //checked
$checkbox->getFont()->setSize(18);

$checkbox = $objRichText->createTextRun('☐');// empty
$checkbox->getFont()->setSize(18);

// add some extra spacing to the cell to make it fit better
$necessarySpacing = str_repeat(' ', floor(count($value) * 2));
$objRichText->createTextRun($necessarySpacing);

$doc->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', $objRichText);
```